# Android NetworkUsage Sample Project Not Working: Lost Connection

Tags: android, networking, android-studio, connectivity

I am trying to run the NetworkUsage sample project app on Android Studio. I downloaded the project from [NetworkUsage.zip](https://developer.android.com/shareables/training/NetworkUsage.zip) and imported it into Android Studio. The project builds without a problem, but when it runs on the emulator, but ends up with a message in the UI: "Lost Connection" followed by "Unable to Load Content. Check Your Network Connection".

When tracing through the execution, I see that when onStart() is called, it calls updateConnectedFlags(). Within this method,

```
activeInfo != null && activeInfo.isConnected()
```

is a true statement, but execution of:

```
    wifiConnected = activeInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
    mobileConnected = activeInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
```

results in wifiConnected = false and mobileConnected being true. That seems a bit odd that the mobileConnected would be true since this is an emulator running. Afterwords, the method onReceive() in the class NetworkReceiver is called, but the following statement fails:

```
if (WIFI.equals(sPref) && networkInfo != null
                && networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
```

because networkInfo.getType() = 0 and ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI = 1 (networkInfo is not null and sPref = WIFI). This results in "Lost Connection".

The only runtime errors I see when I run the project are:

```
03-14 11:28:36.078    2918-2918/com.example.android.networkusage W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
03-14 11:28:36.227    2918-2939/com.example.android.networkusage W/AudioManagerAndroid﹕ Requires BLUETOOTH permission
03-14 11:28:36.211    2918-2918/com.example.android.networkusage W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(315)] locale_file_path.empty()
03-14 11:28:36.267    2918-2918/com.example.android.networkusage I/chromium﹕ [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(63)] Load from apk succesful, fd=32 off=46092 len=2953
03-14 11:28:36.269    2918-2918/com.example.android.networkusage I/chromium﹕ [INFO:aw_browser_main_parts.cc(78)] Loading webviewchromium.pak from, fd:33 off:228796 len:643667
03-14 11:28:36.404    2918-2918/com.example.android.networkusage E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(150)] No suitable EGL configs found.
03-14 11:28:36.404    2918-2918/com.example.android.networkusage E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_android.cc(23)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
03-14 11:28:36.404    2918-2918/com.example.android.networkusage E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(940)] GLSurface::InitializeOneOff failed
03-14 11:28:36.714    2918-2945/com.example.android.networkusage W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(901)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
03-14 11:28:36.750    2918-2918/com.example.android.networkusage W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:data_reduction_proxy_settings.cc(403)] SPDY proxy OFF at startup
03-14 11:28:36.910    2918-2918/com.example.android.networkusage W/art﹕ Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
03-14 11:28:36.948    2918-2918/com.example.android.networkusage W/AwContents﹕ onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
```

I am running Android Studio on a Mac. What might be the reason that this sample is failing? Does anyone have experience with the ConnectivityManager that says that wifi does not work with an emulator? I would like to take advantage of this sample software.

Comment: I updated the question because I was mistaken about one point. The results of the connectivityManager test was that wifiConnected = false and mobileConnected being true. That seems a bit odd that the mobileConnected would be true since this is an emulator running. Does anyone have experience with the ConnectivityManager that says that wifi does not work with an emulator?

Comment: If I set wifiConnected to true and remove the onReceive() test for networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI, then the code works. So, there is a definite problem with the ConnectivityManager giving incorrect results. Thoughts?